# checking value of parameters in where clause for applying arbitrary condition

Tags: sql-server

How to checking value of parameters in where clause for applying arbitrary condition, something like this (*we don't want to use generate string script*):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tbl1 
WHERE
    if (@Value1 > 0 && @Value2 > 0)
    {
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tbl2 
                WHERE ColumnT >= @Value1 AND ColumnT <= @Value2 AND Tbl1.Id = Tbl2.Id)
    }
    else if (@Value1 > 0)
    {
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tbl2 
                WHERE ColumnT >= @Value1 AND Tbl1.Id = Tbl2.Id) 
    }
    else if (@Value2 > 0)
    {
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tbl2 
                WHERE ColumnT <= Value2 AND Tbl1.Id = Tbl2.Id)}
    }
```

Comment: Where does that `tbl2` alias come from? What does it refer to?? You're using the `tbl1` alias for both your outer as well as your inner `SELECT` ......

Comment: @marc_s, sorry ,I corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write it like you're trying to - but you can create a `WHERE` condition for your `EXISTS()` clause that should do the same thing, ultimately:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tbl1 
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tbl2
            WHERE Tbl1.Id = Tbl2.Id
              AND (ColumnT >= @Value1 OR @Value1 <= 0)
              AND (ColumnT <= @Value2 OR @Value2 <= 0)
           )
```

Basically, when either `@Value1` or `@Value2` is <= 0, then it's not being compared to `ColumnT` - so this really should do the same thing as you indicated.

Also: I've replaced the table alias for the "inner" `SELECT` (inside the `EXISTS()` clause) with `tbl2` - you had `tbl1` for both the outer and inner `SELECT`'s, but were referring to a `tbl2` alias in the inner `SELECT`. I hope that is what you had intended.

Comment: Great, Thank you so much.